# Do I need my Tourist Card in Chile for domestic flights?

Tags: air-travel, paperwork, domestic-travel, chile, lost-documents

I'm in Chile for another two weeks, but I lost my tourist card (PDI). This shouldn't be much of a problem because I can get a new one at the international police office.

However, tomorrow I have a domestic flight (Santiago to Punta Arenas) and I'm not sure if I need it for that. If so, I might run into a very tight schedule.

Do I need the tourist card for domestic flights or only when I leave the country?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the answer is no.

I went an hour early and got a new PDI at the desk to the  left of the international departures entrance, which took only 5 minutes. I didn't even have to fill in a form, they just checked my passport and printed a new one.

Not once have I been asked to produce it for my flight to Punta Arenas. Good to know

Comment: Glad it worked out. Thanks for circling back and providing an answer for future visitors.